# TootlTip in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning

How to add tooltip to ui:inputSelect tag in salesforce? I have custom field for language selection and i wish to add tooltip to it. Is there any attribute for ui:inputSelect tag for adding tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lightning there is no standard way to display lightning help text along with lightning input fields label as far i know, correct me if I am wrong. So below is the component to add `tooltip` to `ui:inputSelect` tag in salesforce.

**Aura Component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;">Name</label>
    <lightning:helptext content="Please enter your Name" class="customToolTip"/>
    <lightning:input type="text" name="Name" label="Name" variant="label-hidden"/>
</aura:component>
```

**App**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:testComponent />
</aura:application>
```

**And if you want to adjust help text position, you can also use CSS for this as below:**

```
.THIS .customToolTip div{
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
.THIS.customToolTip div{
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

Comment: There is a standard way of providing a helptext/tooltip using `title` attribute of the component, perhaps not the most fancy looking tooltip but its there.

Answer (score 2):

> ui:inputSelect is [Deprecated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:inputSelect/specification) as of API version 47.0. Use
>   lightning:select or lightning:combobox instead.

**Example:**

```
    <lightning:combobox name="progress" 
                        label="Status" 
                        value="inProgress" 
                        placeholder="Select Progress" 
                        options="{! v.options }"
                        fieldLevelHelp="your tooltip" 
                        onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentiined in @Anmol's answer, you should use [`lightning:combobox`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example) or [`lightning:select`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/specification). Now, easiest way to add a tooltip to `lightning:select` is by using its `title` attribute.

e.g.

```
<lightning:select name="select1" label="How many tickets?" required="true" title="this is tooltip!" class="tooltiptext">
    <option value="">choose one...</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</lightning:select>
```